# Need to select rows from Web Table

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I have a web table, which is showing some data based on some search filter criteria. So in actual we have total-50 rows. But after applying filter only 1 is visible on the table.
Here the problem is, in DOM it's showing all 50 rows including that 1 which is visible.

```
<table-row style="height: 32px; line-height: 32px; transform: translateY(0px);">
<table-row style="height: 12px; line-height: 12px; transform: translateY(32px); display:none;">
<table-row style="height: 12px; line-height: 12px; transform: translateY(38px); display:none;">
<table-row style="height: 12px; line-height: 12px; transform: translateY(41px); display:none;">
```

Now the only option i have is to use this display part of attribute-"style"I As i want only those rows, which doesn't contain this display option none in their style attribute am trying a xpath like-
below but it's not working`

```
//table-row[not(contains(@style,'%display: none%')]
```

Comment: Are you sure that your HTML looks like that? I don't see the closing tags (`</table-row >`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove those leading and trailing `%` symbols and add closing bracket:

```
//table-row[not(contains(@style,'display:none;'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It has resolved my query. There was a space , i just removed it and it worked.